# What synergizes with Awesome Display?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

I'm thinking about building a Heavens Oracle with [*Awesome Display*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/baseClasses/oracle.html#awesome-display), and I'm looking for things that synergize well with that, especially at higher levels where [Color Spray](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/colorSpray.html#_color-spray) will not be effective, even with the benefits of Awesome Display, high charisma, and feats.  The usual options are obvious:

- Gnome (+2 Charisma and +1 to Illusion DCs)
- Maximum Charisma
- Spell Penetration and Greater Spell Penetration
- Spell Focus Illusion and Greater Spell Focus Illusion

Are there other character options that synergize well with this ability and allow it to be useful even at higher levels?

---

Note: My GM and I have negotiated a minimum 1/4 HD for purposes of *Awesome Display*.  A creature would be reduced from to 1 HD, then 1/2, then 1/4 so if I have a +5 charisma a 3 HD creature would could as 1/4 HD for spells such as *hypnotic pattern*.

Comment: @HeyICanChan My GM and I negotiated minimum 1/4.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Do you want to suggest a way of getting *scintillating pattern* as an Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

The Heavens mystery already gives you most of the spells that work with Awesome Display: color spray, hypnotic pattern, and rainbow pattern. About the only one you're missing is [Scintillating Pattern](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/scintillatingPattern.html#_scintillating-pattern).

If you want Scintillating pattern, the only good way I know of to get it as an Oracle spell is to be an Elf for the oracle archetype [Ancient Lorekeeper](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/coreRaces/elves.html#ancient-lorekeeper-%28oracle%29), at which point you can select it as your level 9 bonus spell (instead of its usual level 8 spell status)

However, that hurts your charisma due to a lack of a CHA race bonus, which is the last thing you want to do with this build, so consider asking your GM if a Half-Elf would qualify for that archetype due to elf blood. If so, that's probably the way to go if you want Scintillating pattern. At a level 9 spell, that's pretty late to plan for though...

Aside from that, boost your charisma like mad of course. +6 Headband, inherent bonus from tome, and so on.

If you have 2-3 spare feats, something any character can do to make your spells harder to save against is getting [Nature's Soul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/nature-soul) and [Animal Ally](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/animal-ally) (Boon companion optional) and building the animal companion as a [Dazzling Display](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dazzling-display-combat) build to apply Shaken to the enemies for -2 to their saves.

Lastly, get the [Seeker oracle archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/archetypes/paizo---oracle-archetypes/seeker). Among other perks (Trapfinding) you get +4 to overcome spell resistance with your bonus spells (i.e. all your pattern spells)

Comment: Welcome to RPG StackExchange! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You [need not ask your GM](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qf9) about selecting Ancient Lorekeeper as a half-elf, provided they trust the Pathfinder FAQ (which is rather controversial among those with game mastery).